# Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $f(0)=0$, $f'(x)>f(x), \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Question: Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $f(0)=0$, $f'(x)>f(x), \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f(x)>0, \forall x>0$.

Solution: Let $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be such that $h(x)=e^{-x}f(x),\forall x\in\mathbb{R}.$ Observe that $h$ is a differentiable function and $$h'(x)=e^{-x}(f'(x)-f(x)), \forall x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Also $h(0)=0$.

Now select any $x>0$. Thus applying MVT to the function $h$ on the interval $[0,x]$, we can conclude that $\exists c\in(0,x)$, such that $$h'(c)=\frac{h(x)-h(0)}{x-0}=\frac{h(x)}{x}\implies h(x)=xh'(c).$$

Now since, $h'(c)=e^{-c}(f'(c)-f(c))\implies h(x)=xe^{-c}(f'(c)-f(c)).$

Again since we have $f'(x)>f(x), \forall x\in\mathbb{R}\implies f'(c)-f(c)>0,$ which in turn implies that $xe^{-c}(f'(c)-f(c))>0\implies h(x)>0.$

Thus we have $h(x)=e^{-x}f(x)>0\implies f(x)>0.$

Hence, we can conclude that $f(x)>0, \forall x>0.$

Is there any other way to prove the same?

Comment: This is an idea - 

Let D be the set of x such that f(x) > 0. 
Consider the set $\{s | (0, s) \subseteq D \}$ which is a connected interval. Then maybe you can say something about its supremum having to be infinity, via contradiction? 

In other words, if it takes the form (0, t) then the function must be 0 at t, but positive before that, which seems to be a contradiction to the derivative property you stated.

Comment: you are overcomplicating it. Once you have $h'(x)>0$, then $h$ is strictly increasing, so $h(x)>h(0) = 0$, for $x > 0.$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose not. Then the intermediate value theorem implies the set $S = \{x>0:f(x)=0\}$ is non-empty. Put $C=\inf S$.

If $C=0$, we have a strictly decreasing sequence $a_i$ (each $a_i>0$) converging to $0$ such that $f(a_i)=0$ for each $i$. By considering quotients $\frac{f(a_i)-f(0)}{a_i-0}$, we see that this implies $f'(0)=0$, contradicting $f'(0)>f(0)=0$. Hence $C>0$, and we must have $f(C)=0$ by continuity. We have that $f(x)$ vanishes nowhere in $(0, C)$, so by continuity it is the same sign on $(0,C)$. The sign must be positive, namely $f(x)>0$ for all $x \in (0,C)$, since otherwise $f'(0)>0$ would be manifestly impossible (note $f(0)=0$). Thus, at this stage we have that $f(0)=f(C)=0$, and $f(x)>0$ for all $x \in (0,C)$. Rolle's theorem implies $f'(\gamma)=0$ for some $\gamma \in (0,C)$. We have $f(\gamma)>0$. Hence $f(\gamma)>f'(\gamma)$, contradicting one of the hypotheses.

Comment: I was writing an answer and then saw yours which uses same idea so I stopped. +1